# Getting "rpm: -–import: unknown option" when tryihng to import public key on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rpm, public-key

I’m tryhing to install Google Chrome on Amazon Linux using this site — , and one of the steps is

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo rpm -–import linux_signing_key.pub
```

Unfortunately, when I try this, I get the error

```
rpm: -–import: unknown option
```

Is there another way I should be installing this?  It is not an option to change to a different version of Linux at this time, sadly.